# Google Maps Directions API Usage Limits

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

What is the limit of allowed waypoints in the free plan of Google Maps Directions API? Their site indicates this:

> Up to 23 waypoints allowed in each request containing an API key, or up to 8 waypoints when no API key is supplied, or up to 8 waypoints when using the Directions service in the Google Maps JavaScript API

Which is unclear, because first it tells you that you're allowed to use 23 waypoints when you have a key, and lastly it says that you're only allowed to use 8.

Comment: This question should not be down voted at all, +1. I'm facing the same issue and came here after a search request on Google. Thanks @geocodezip for posting the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this issue in the issue tracker: [Issue 8886:   Bug: Directions API description of MAX_WAYPOINTS_EXCEEDED is not clear](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8886)

from that issue:

> **Nov 16, 2015**
>
> Project Member #8 andr...@google.com
>
> The post refers to Web Services.
>
> The situation is the following:
>
> - Web Services (Directions API, Distance Matrix API) both free users (API keys) and Maps for Work users (client ID + signature) have 23 waypoints
> - JavaScript API (directions service, distance matrix service): free users (API keys) have 8 waypoints, Maps for Work users (client ID) have 23 waypoints.
>
> **Jan 22, 2016**
>
> Project Member #12 ekelar...@google.com
>
> we're looking into adding this to JavaScript API as well, but there are some blockers on this, so we decided to roll it out for the web services without waiting for JS.